# How to block comments with long lines ( with no breaks ) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I need to block comments with long lines without break like below

[image]

i checked worpress admin and found the option

> Comment Blacklist When a comment contains any of these words in its
>   content, name, URL, e-mail, or IP, it will be marked as spam. One word
>   or IP per line. It will match inside words, so “press” will match
>   “WordPress”.

but i am not sure what to write in it

Comment: The option you found is to block specific words, not general text that fits a certain pattern.  I think you will need a different solution.  If your concern is that long words are breaking your site's design, here is a discussion of how to make these words wrap: http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/

Comment: As a hotfix, i would add `word-wrap:break-word` into the skin's css file.